# python-ldap -- User Creation in Active Directory -- problem 2003 (BAD_ATT_SYNTAX) cn and DN

Tags: python, linux, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I am writing a Python script using the python-ldap module with the purpose of creating users in Active Directory, Windows 2012R2 Server.

The problem I am facing is when the NEW DN I am creating got a syntax such us :

DN: cn=Name Second_name,.etc..

It seems to only accept a format such as :

DN: cn=NameSecond_name,.etc..
  or
DN: cn=Name,.etc..

Also this issue happens with the **cn** attribute.

My code so far is as follows:

```
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist
import base64, sys

DN, secret = sys.argv[1:3]

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://ldap_server')

l.simple_bind_s(DN,secret)


name = "name"
second_name = "secondname"
fullname = name + " " + second_name
mail = "name_secondname@company.com"
company_id = "id1234"
password = "passsword"

base_dn = "OU=Accounts,DC=internal"
user_dn = 'CN=' + name + ' '  + second_name + ',' + base_dn

user_attrs = {}
user_attrs['objectclass'] = ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user']
user_attrs['cn'] = full_name
user_attrs['givenName'] = str(name)
user_attrs['sn'] = str(second_name)
user_attrs['displayName'] = "%s" % full_name
user_attrs['userAccountControl'] = '514'
user_attrs['mail'] = mail
user_attrs['uid'] = company_id
user_attrs['countryCode'] = '0'
user_attrs['primaryGroupID'] = '513',
user_attrs['userPrincipalName'] = '%s@company.internal' % str(company_id)
user_attrs['sAMAccountname'] = "%s" % srt(company_id)
user_ldif = modlist.addModlist(user_attrs)

unicode_pass = unicode('\"' + password + '\"', 'iso-8859-1')
password_value = unicode_pass.encode('utf-16-le')

add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password_value])]
# 512 will set user account to enabled
mod_acct = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'userAccountControl', '512')]


l.add_s(user_dn, user_ldif)
l.modify_s(user_dn, add_pass)
l.modify_s(user_dn, mod_acct)
```

The error I am currently getting is the following:

```
    l.add_s(user_dn, user_ldif)
  File "/home/edevi98/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 430, in add_s
    return self.add_ext_s(dn,modlist,None,None)
  File "/home/edevi98/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 416, in add_ext_s
    resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid, resp_ctrls = self.result3(msgid,all=1,timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/home/edevi98/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 751, in result3
    resp_ctrl_classes=resp_ctrl_classes
  File "/home/edevi98/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 758, in result4
    ldap_result = self._ldap_call(self._l.result4,msgid,all,timeout,add_ctrls,add_intermediates,add_extop)
  File "/home/edevi98/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 331, in _ldap_call
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "/home/edevi98/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 315, in _ldap_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)

ldap.INVALID_DN_SYNTAX: {'info': u"00002081: NameErr: DSID-03050CF6, problem 2003 (BAD_ATT_SYNTAX), data 0, best match of:\n\t'CN=name secondname,OU=Accounts,DC=internal'\n", 'desc': u'Invalid DN syntax'}
```

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base dn is incomplete, the domain components (DCs) must refer to each component of your domain.

For example the domain *internal.com* would be written as `DC=internal,DC=com`, and the base dn (as all dn in this directory tree) must match these DCs :

```
base_dn = "OU=Accounts,DC=internal,DC=com"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was down to a syntax error in the formatting in python

it should be:

```
user_dn = 'CN=' + name + ' ' + second_name + ',' + base_dn
```

and

```
fullname = name + ' ' + second_name
```

Otherwise it works fine now.